# Multiple Webpack builds based on file extension

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a build configuration in Webpack going similar to how react-native handle ios/android builds based on the extensions: .ios.js and .android.js respectively.

To elaborate, given this directory structure:

```
app/
  index.js
  components/
    button.web.js
    button.mobile.js
```

I'd like to get

```
build/
  web/app.js
  mobile/app.js
```

Does anyone have an idea if this is even possible with webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using `resolve.extensions`. For example this webpack configuration snippet:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.mobile.js']
}
```

will cause Webpack to look for `button`, `button.js` and finally `button.mobile.js` when encountering `require('./button')`. You can make the extension a command-line parameter. For example, if you add `yargs` to your project and use it like so in the webpack config file:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
... {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.' + argv.target + '.js']
    }
}
```

then `webpack --target=mobile` will also include `.mobile.js` files in the bundle, likewise for `webpack --target=web` or any other target.

Note that if both `button.js` and `button.mobile.js` exist, the first one to be found will be required and all the rest - ignored. If you have both common and platform-specific parts of a component, you will have to put the two parts into files with different names and `require` both - for example `button.js` and `button-platform.mobile.js`; then `var button = require('./button'); var buttonPlatform = require('./button-platform');` and merge the two.

**EDIT: Answer to second part of the question**

The sought output folder structure can be created, again, using `yargs` - just plug the `--target` argument from above into the `output` section of the webpack config:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, argv.target);
  filename: 'app.js'
}
```

Comment: @StefanDragnev How are you importing the `Button` component? `import Button from 'components/Button'`?

Comment: Um, yes. Without extension z if that's what you're asking